# How to add a List of Users in a User Class using EF CodeFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm creating my `DB using EF CodeFirst`.

I have created the following User Class-

```
 public class User
    {
        public User()
        {

        }

        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required, MinLength(4), MaxLength(20)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required, MinLength(8), MaxLength(40)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required, MinLength(8), MaxLength(15)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime JoinedOn { get; set; }

        public List<Users> Friends { get; set; } // Problem Adding List of Users in User Class
    }
```

I want to store the `List of friends for each user`. And, I'm unable to add a `Friends collection` property to this `User Class`.

I have spent a lot of time trying this.

Is there any way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code solved my problem-

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
        Friends = new List<User>();
        ChatRooms = new List<ChatRoom>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required, MinLength(4), MaxLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, MinLength(8), MaxLength(40)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required, MinLength(8), MaxLength(15)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime JoinedOn { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Friends")]
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Friends { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Participants")]
    public virtual ICollection<ChatRoom> ChatRooms { get; set; }
}
```

I just added-

```
[InverseProperty("Friends")]
public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<User> Friends { get; set; }
```

Thanks! Everyone...